# How to mask url in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, url-masking

I would like the following to happen:

When a visitor types an incorrect URL on my website, I would like it to redirect the visitor to a custom error page that I made. However I want the URL to show `www.example.com` while the error page itself might be `www.example.com/errorDocs/404.error`.

This is what I currently have but it does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com

ErrorDocument 403 RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com/errorDocs/403.html?$ ./

ErrorDocument 404 RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com/errorDocs/404.html?$ ./
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sample rewrite rule will look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^directory/?$ /directory/page/
```

This way each time someone accesses:

http://xyzdomain00.com/directory

the actual content that will be displayed will be for:

http://xyzdomain00.com/directory/page